# i run my project and get following error in my build.gradle file what should i do?

Tags: android

Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'My Quotes', project ':app'

Comment: Please make your question more clearer so that it will be easily readable to resolve your problem. Also please revisit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

just delete that repo from your project gradle file

Comment: yes, I have deleted but it is not working                i got the solution   we have to replace jcenter() with mavenCentral()